# How to make Images not Zoom when using Body Zoom

Tags: css, image, safari, zooming

I have an interesting question. I have a laptop that the resolution makes it difficult for me to read the text. I found that placing a css file in Safari allows for the text to permanently be larger, however I ran into an issue using

```
    Body {zoom: 110%}
```

My images are zooming as well and always look distorted.

Is there a way to only zoom the text and not affect the images?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively in Safari, under `Preferences > Advanced Tab > Universal Access` you can set a minimum font size.[image]